# node_interface for now?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node_interfaces (https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/tree/master/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node_interfaces) are really useful for dependency injection allowing much nicer tests.  There however does not seem to be an interface that provides the method `now`.  Is there a way to call that method without a node interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382823/node_interface-for-now?/) by [tylerjw](https://answers.ros.org/users/58958/tylerjw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that you can get a NodeClockInterface and gen call now like this: `node_clock_interface->get_clock()->now()`

---

Originally posted by [tylerjw](https://answers.ros.org/users/58958/tylerjw/) with karma: 83 on 2021-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2